# ECG 60 Hz noise filtering in Python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I got some ECG data from a acquisition circuit developed in the lab where I work, and I'm trying to implement a 60 Hz notch filter to minimize the background noise.

Here is the code:

```
from scipy import fft
from scipy import ifft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def notchfilter(ECGdata):
""" Filters the data using notch filter

    Description:
        Digital filter which returns the filtered signal using 60Hz
        notch filter. Transforms the signal into frequency domain
        using the fft function of the Scipy Module. Then, suppresses
        the 60Hz signal by equating it to zero. Finally, transforms
        the signal back to time domain using the ifft function.
    Input:
        ECGdata -- list of integers (ECG data)
    Output:
        ifft(fftECG) -- inverse fast fourier transformed array of filtered ECG data
"""         
fftECG = fft(ECGdata)
for i in range(len(fftECG)):
    if 590<i<620 or 880<i<910: fftECG[i]=0
return ifft(fftECG)

data = open('ECG_LOG4.TXT','r')
y = data.readlines()
data.close()

t = range(len(y))

plt.plot(t,y)
plt.show()
```

But I'm getting this error:

"TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('U1') to dtype('complex128') according to the rule 'safe'."

The input data ('ECG_LOG4.txt') is a list with sampled data:

312\n
319\n
312\n
290\n
296\n
309\n
309\n...

Any idea? I'm a python begginer, so I have no idea for where to start to solve.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that your data is read as strings. Try using `numpy.loadtxt()`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that in a cleaner way using the frequency.

```
fs = 160 # pulling rate
N = len(ECGdata)
T = 1/fs
t = np.arange(0,N/fs,T)
f = np.fft.fftfreq(N,T)
fft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(ECGdata))


min = 59.8
max = 60.2

fft[(f>min) & (f<max)] = 0
```

Keep in mind that you should fine-tune the min and max values.